# Read the json with sub array values and display on the html using ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mat-table, mat-chip

Hi I am developing a web app where I am display a student data received in json format.

Here is the typescript code snippet

```
    export interface studentData{
      ID : number;
      Name :string;
      Class : string;
      Languages: string;
    }
    
    const STUDENT_DATA: studentData[] = 
    [
     {
      ID : 1
      Name: "Amy",
      Class: "Grade1",
      Languages: "Java, .net, Python"
     },
     {
      ID : 2
      Name: "John",
      Class: "Grade2",
      Languages: "Kotlin, Java, Typescript"
     },
     {
      ID: 3
      Name: "Shawn",
      Class: "Grade3",
      Languages: "Javascript, C++, Perl"
     },
    ]
export class StudentDataComponent{
       languages : string[] = [];
    for (let i=0; i <= STUDENT_DATA.length - 1 ; i++)
     {
       this.languages = STUDENT_DATA[i].Languages.split(",");
     }
}
```

I tried to make Languages as separate array and thought to use it while displaying on screen using ngFor

```
languages : string[] = [];
for (let i=0; i <= STUDENT_DATA.length - 1 ; i++)
 {
   this.languages = STUDENT_DATA[i].Languages.split(",");
 }
```

I tried to display in mat-chip-list as shown below but it just displays ID 3 languages for all ID's

```
<mat-chip-list>
   <mat-chip *ngFor = "let lang of languages>
         {{lang}}
   </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

Need help to read the languages json value and display over screen.

Comment: Does your actual code miss the end quote in your ngFor? Also, it looks like `this.languages` would just end up being the languages for the last student.

Comment: Why are looping through student data and recreating the scope variable `this.languages` with each one? Do you mean to be creating a separate array for each student?

Answer (score 1):

"it just displays ID 3 languages for all ID's"

this is because you are setting `this.language` to the first, then the second... at the end it just ends up being the last item. You don't have a separate one for each student.

I think a better alternative would be to add a property on each student object. Something like:

```
this.students = STUDENT_DATA.map(s => {
    ...s,
    LanguageArray: s.Language.split(",").map(l => l.trim())
});
```

then this would just be part of the student data which I assume you are looping through outside of the `mat-chip`.. so you could do something like `*ngFor="let lang of student.LanguageArray` inside of your `*ngFor="let student of students"`

Answer (score 1):

If you're just wanting to loop through the languages string for each student in the loop, you can do your `split()` inline with a second ngFor, as in

```
<div *ngFor="let student of STUDENT_DATA">
 <!-- .... -->
  <mat-chip-list>
     <mat-chip *ngFor="let lang of student.languages.split(',')">
         {{lang}}
     </mat-chip>
  </mat-chip-list>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code currently overwrites the language variable during every iteration. Modify the type of languages and add index also to languages variable:

```
let languages: string[][] = [];

for (let i = 0; i <= STUDENT_DATA.length - 1; i++) {
    languages[i] = STUDENT_DATA[i].Languages.split(",");
}
```

Code should be something like that:

```
<student-element *ngFor="let student of STUDENT_DATA; index as i">
// Element code here
<mat-chip-list>
  <mat-chip *ngFor = "let lang of languages[i]">
    {{lang}}
  </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
</student-element>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. STUDENT_DATA array of type studentData is declared SutdentDataComponent so when I use the STUDENT_DATA in HTML I am getting "Error occurs on the template of component StudentDataComponent"

Comment: Try to declare or initialize the STUDENT_DATA variable inside StudentDataComponent.

Comment: It outputs data with all subjects for each student. Anything I am missing here. Appreciated your help

Comment: We should really see the code in order to give further guidance. Would you like to publish your code on Stackblitz?